# Mongodb if exist override

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb to communicate with `Mongodb` from `Spring boot`.

Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a324f8bc23fa147699ee0fb"),
    "_class" : "com.mongodb.User",
    "name" : "Prakash",
    "userId" : NumberLong(1000),
    "organisation" : "Inbytes",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-12-14T10:16:43.173Z")
}
```

**With index** : userId (unique)

If I insert any document having `"userId" : NumberLong(1000)` **i.e already exist**,
then I get **this error**:

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.user index: userId dup key: { : 1000 }"
    }
})
```

I have a use-case in which I have to update 1 million records daily. They may change their fields like name, points,  etc...

One way to achieve this use-case is by:

`find if they exist, if exist, update or override, else insert`.

But this method has high latency for huge records.

Is there exist a better way to achieve my use-case. Both native MongoDB-java and spring mongo-DB repository will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

> duplicate key error

because you've `Indexed` your `Mongo` `collection`.

The fact is that if there is already existing index with name you are trying to insert another document then it will not let you insert. **Because indexes are unique.**

> One way to achieve this use-case is by:
>
> find if they exist, if exist, update or override, else insert

Obviously, YES. Because you can only update  on some indexed collection but you cannot insert any other Document with the same `Index`.

Comment: If I insert a document with primary index, if it exist, it overrides the existing document. Can we achieve this  behaviour in case of unique index. I.e it should update/override other fields of documents (other thana_id and field with unique  index) if the document with unique index exist.